# Reverse for 'details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried:

Tags: django

I can't seem to spot the error in my code and I have tried everything. It is probably something simple that is escaping my eye. Please help! Any input is appreciated. New Django learner here.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\doctrinality\doctrinality\Testimony\views.py", line 175, in TestimonyOrderView
    return render(request, 'testimony_post.html', {'queryset_list':queryset_list})
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 188, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 173, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 442, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 90, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 622, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<id>[0-9]+)/details(?P<format>\\.[a-z0-9]+/?)$', '(?P<id>[0-9]+)/details/$']
[16/Jan/2019 21:58:50] "GET /testimonypost/ HTTP/1.1" 500 187935
```

template

```
{%for objects in queryset_list%}
<div class="w3-card-4">
  <header class="w3-container w3-blue">
    <h1><a href="{% url 'details' testimony.id %}"</a>{{testimony.Title}}</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="w3-container">
    <p>{{objects.body}}</p>
  </div>

  <footer class="w3-container w3-blue">

  </footer>

</div>
<form action="{% url 'testimonydelete'%}" method="POST" style="display">
<button class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></button>
</form>
{%endfor%}
```

models.py

```
class Testimony(models.Model):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return int(self.id)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<int:id>/details/', views.detail, name='details'),
]
```

views.py

```
def details(request, id=None):
    print('1')
    testimony=get_object_or_404(Testimony, id=id)
    print('2')
    return render(request, 'details.html', {'testimony': testimony})
```

Comment: Your variable is `testimony` with a lowercase, hence it should be `{% url 'details' testimony.id %}`.

Comment: Shouldn't the tag variable match the one in my models.py?

Comment: no, since only things you pass through the context (together with filters, tags, context processors that you pass implictly) exist in the "template space".

Comment: Still seeing the same error though.

Comment: @HANYAUFOONG: does your template contains other `{% url ... %}`s? Can you show the full error message (including details)?

Comment: just edited my template. And yes, i do have 2 urls. is that the bug i am missing all along?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the variable in the for loop is actually `objects`, for some reason. So, just like you use `objects.body` to display the body, you need `objects.id` in the URL:

```
<h1><a href="{% url 'details' objects.id %}"</a>{{ objects.Title }}</h1>
```

Comment: That was my thought as well, but in that case @HANYAOFOONG would have posted the wrong view code...

Comment: Not sure what documentation you want. It's just a matter of using the variables you defined.